# How to include a specific list of files in `src`?

Tags: nix

This derivation seems to include all files in the current directory, recursively, as expected:

```
src = builtins.path {
  name = pname;
  path = ./.;
};
```

I'd like to only include a small subset of that; `content/index.html` and `package.json`. But my filter seems to be excluding everything:

```
src = builtins.path {
  name = pname;
  path = ./.;
  filter = path: type:
    builtins.elem path [
      ./content/index.html
      ./package.json
    ];
};
```

At least according to `pkgs.mkYarnPackage`:

> error: opening file '/nix/store/[…]/package.json': No such file or directory

What's wrong with my filter?

The following filter *does* work, but is a bit of a hack:

```
filter = path: type:
  builtins.elem (baseNameOf path) [
    "index.html"
    "package.json"
  ];
```

I guess there's some issue with the equality of `./package.json` and the `src` entry. Are the paths returned by `builtins.path` not the same data type/values as `./foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56312855/96588): converting `builtins.path` entries to paths is as simple as this:

```
filter = path: type:
  builtins.elem (/. + path) [
    ./content
    ./content/index.html
    ./package.json
  ];
```

(You have to list each directory in addition to its contents.)